# could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = example@example.com limit 1) laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Muy buena a todos solicito su ayuda ya que estoy trabajando con laravel, ayer todo funcionaba bien el problema es que hoy al iniciar laravel e iniciar sesion en mi página obtengo este error:

```
could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` =  example@example.com limit 1)
```

Investigue un poco y creo que ese problema pasa porque no tengo algunos paquetes instalados, pero al parecer tengo todo lo necesario, ya que como mencioné ayer funcionaba todo bien. También otro problema que obtengo es al querer hacer las migraciones obtengo esta salida:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "curl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Nothing to migrate
```

Realmente no se porque podría pasar esto ni como puedo solucionarlo, así que agradezco su ayuda. Desde ya gracias :).

**Edit**

Al parecer me hacía falta instalar PHP pdo_mysql como dijeron en los comentarios, ya lo instalé, todo funciona correctamente y ya puedo iniciar sesión, lo malo es que el problema al hacer las migraciones contingua, y al ejecute `php artisan serve` obtengo este resultado:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "curl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Mon Jan 17 14:16:28 2022] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Jan 17 14:16:28 2022] PHP Warning:  Module "curl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Me gustaría aclarar que los errores que obtengo no evitan lo que se supone que deben hacer los comandos, por ejemplo `php artisan migrate` muestra advertencias y despues hace las migraciones, y `php artisan serve` muestra igual advertencias y despues sigue todo normal, aunque los errores no son como el anterior me gustaría que me ayudaran a evitar que salgan esas advertencias. Gracias.

Comment: Coloca tu código de conexión en la pregunta pulsando en [edit], pues parece que estás pasando una consulta SQL en vez del controlador cuando intentas conectar a la BD.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿a qué parte del código específicamente te refieres con "tu código de conexión"? ya que por el momento tengo todo normal como lo deja laravel por defecto. Saludos :)

Comment: ¿El email `example@example.com`no tendria que ir entrecomillado?

Comment: @masterguru creo que si, pero como mencioné, el proyecto laravel ayer funcionaba correctamente tal y como estaba, ¿en qué parte puedo editar la consulta que hace laravel al iniciar sesión?

Comment: Parece que te falta la extensión PHP pdo_mysql en el sistema